# Double connected minimal surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Assume that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two Jordan curves in two parallel planes $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ (paralel to $xOy$ plane) so that projection of $\gamma_2$ in $\Pi_1$ is inside of $\gamma_1$. Assume that $\Sigma$ is a minimal surface spanning $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Whether $\Sigma$ is a graph of some function defined in $\Omega=\Omega(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)$, where  is a double connected domain bounded by the projections of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in  $xOy$ plane

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Consider the [cathenoide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid). You can choose boundary
curves in parallel planes so that your assertion does not hold.

Comment: Dear Alexandre Eremenko, what it happens if the planes are close enough?

Comment: @Lira, does not matter. Look at the picture carefully. You can cut a part of this picture with two parallel plane at any distance, so that the part between them is not a graph of a function. While intersections with the planes are circles.